# Is there specific software to create alarm tones?

Tags: audio

I'm looking to recreate some of the alarm tones found in aircraft, without just using just a recording. Some of the tones I am trying to recreate are found in a video like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W5Z-d1Zx02o). I have been unable to find any software that allows for the creation of these types of beeps and such. I've tried to use software like Audacity to generate tones but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you used "audio frequency generator software" as search terms?